# where to put Fb login button with condition in container

Tags: facebook, authentication, flutter, dart, google-signin

I'm new to flutter.
I am integrating google and facebook sign in to single page.I've set google sign in btn in container. Plz let me know where can I put fb login button with login-logout condition in same container. here's my code.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: _isLoggedIn
                ? Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(_googleSignIn.currentUser.photoUrl, height: 50.0, width: 50.0,),
                Text(_googleSignIn.currentUser.displayName),
                OutlineButton( child: Text("Logout"), onPressed: (){
                  _logout();
                },)
              ],
            )
                : Center(
              child: OutlineButton(
                child: Text("Login with Google"),
                onPressed: () {
                  _login();
                },
              ),
            ) ,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Center(
          child: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
             children:[
               OutlineButton(
                 child: Text("Login with Google"),
                 onPressed: () {
                 _login();
               },
              ),
             OutlineButton(
                 child: Text("Login with Facebook"),
                 onPressed: () {
                 //Todo
               },
              ),
        ) ,
```

Comment: thanks but I want to use condition like this:  child: _isLoggedIn? Column() : Center() for both

Comment: If the user logged in you want to show facebook login option ?